# OSGB36 referenced PNG to Google Earth

Tags: gdal, google-earth, c++, ordnance-survey

I am creating a PNG that is referenced to the OSGB36 datum (1 pixel per 50m easting/northing that is colored according to the result of some calculation code)

I want to display this on Google Earth using KML. But obviously I need to transform the image before I do this.

I can manually use gdal_translate to create a TIF file then gdalwarp to convert the image but I want to achieve this in code (C++) not via external applications.

I looked at the GDAL API but having no joy doing what I can easily do with the aforementioned GDAL utilities.

http://wtp2.appspot.com/warpdemo.htm seems to doing something similar to what I want but having looked at the JavaScript I don't really understand how the affine transformation is being constructed.

Any pointers on how to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: wtp2 demo by Bill Chadwick uses the Ordnance Survey OpenSpace API - you can view the javascript code at http://wtp2.appspot.com/warped_os.js and is pulling the tiles from http://openspace.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/osmapapi/

Comment: Yes I have seen that. To be honest I can't really work out how the affine transformation is being constructed and how I could modify it for my scenario.

Comment: In the end I used ShellExecuteEx to run gdalwarp. I would still be interested in a pure C++ code solution but for now this will have to do.